# Prometheus - create a new label from file_sd configs address

Tags: prometheus, monitoring

I have a few file_sd configs with targets in format 'ip hostname'
e.g. '10.10.11.12 foo'

I need to extract foo value to the new label "hostname" and then add add port value ":9100" to ip and assign it to target_label: instance

I tried to use code bellow, but unfortunately it doesn’t work.

```
relabel_configs:
  - source_labels: [__address__]
    regex: '([^ ]+)'   
    target_label: instance
  - source_labels: [__address__]
    regex: '(.+)(.+)'  
    target_label: instance
    replacement: '${1}'
  - source_labels: [__address__]
    regex: '(.+)(.+)'  
    target_label: __address__
    replacement: '${2}'
  - source_labels: [__address__]
    target_label: __address__
    replacement: '${1}:9100'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally got the solution

```
relabel_configs:
  - source_labels: [__address__]
    regex: "(.+) (.+)"
    replacement: "$2"
    target_label: hostname
  - source_labels: [__address__]
    regex: "(.+) (.+)"
    replacement: "$1"
    target_label: "ip"
  - source_labels: [__address__]
    regex: "(.+) (.+)"
    replacement: "$1:9100"
    target_label: __address__
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).